# many to many relationship between users and books,books wont appear in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I am trying to show a list of user's books,but for some reason the saved books won't appear on the view.The application is supposed to allow a signed in user to save books and then show list of books saved by that particular user. Here is my code..

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<%=link_to 'add a book',new_book_path%>
<ul>
 <% @books.each do |b|%>
 <li><%= b.title %></li>
 <li><%= b.author %></li>
 <%end%>
 </ul>
```

BOOK CONTROLLER

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
def index

 end

def create

@book=current_user.books.build(params[:book])
if @book.save
redirect_to '/home/index'
else
  render :action =>'new'
end
end


def new
@book=Book.new
end
end
```

Home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
#kip_before_filter    :authenticate_user! 
 #efore_filter :homenticate_user! 

 def index
  @books=current_user.books

 end

 def show
 end

 def welcome

 end
 end
```

Book model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :book_ownerships
has_many :users,:through => :book_ownerships
end
```

User model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :book_ownerships
 has_many :books,:through => :book_ownerships
 has_many :skills
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 

     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:firstname
  end
```

Book ownership model

```
 class BookOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :book
 end
```

Book view

```
<h1>Book#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/book/index.html.erb</p>
 <%= form_for(@book) do |f|%>
 <%=f.text_field :title%>
 <%=f.text_field :author%>
 <%=f.submit%>
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the first view in your example actually is `Books#index` and not `Home#index` and if that is true then you need to set the variable `@books` to something in the controller.

It should be enough to make the index action in your BooksController look like this:

```
def index
  @books = current_user.books
end
```

At least if you are using Rails 3. If you are on an earlier version then you should add the call to the all method like this:

```
@books = current_user.books.all
```

Comment: @dannmanne No it is Homeindex like it is,i want to show the books on homeindex view..thank you

Comment: Okey, in that case could you complement with the code from your Home#index controller action? Would be helpful to see how that looks like.

Comment: @katie you need to setup the instance variable in your home_controller's index action just as Danne has shown above.  I'm also guessing that you're authorising the controller via Devise's before_filter - if not, do not assume current_user exists.

Comment: @dannmanne I have added home controller above...@mike need to show the books in the home view,that is why

Comment: Your code looks like it should work when I look at it. Are you sure that the current_user actually has any books in the database? If you are then I would recommend some debug logging, for example putting this in your index action in the home controller: `logger.info(current_user.inspect)` and `logger.info(@books.inspect)` and then start going through your log file

Comment: @dannemanne yes there are books in the database..when i do  @books=Book.all it returns all the books.I think it has to do with the particular user saving the book which is @book=current_user.books.build(params[:book])...since it is many to many relationship..but i dont know how to make it work